# Change names of navigations from rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I want to change the names of few navigations of my rails admin dashboard. I am fairly new to rails and I am bit confused about how can I do that.

For eg suppose [This](http://rails-admin-tb.herokuapp.com/) app's navigation needs to be changed, I am not sure which files to be changed to acheive that.

[Here's](https://github.com/bbenezech/dummy_app) the dummy app for the same app I found in `rails_admin wiki`.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to learn rails and active_admin I'd recommend you look for something more recent than the repo you mention. Both frameworks changed a lot in the past 4 years and things are simpler now. [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/) website gives you all you need.

Comment: I know bit of rails. Also, I am not using `active_admin`. I am using `gem 'rails_admin'`

Comment: My mistake, apologies! Still that dummy_app is very old...

Comment: what I want to learn is how can I rename the navigations out there. So the latest `rails_admin` dashboard is not too different from this

Answer (score 0):

You have to config the model's info (e.g., on a rails_admin initializer) in order to change the navigation. [Here you have](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Navigation) the wiki page with the config info for the model's navigation.

In the `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` file ([here you have](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/generators/rails_admin/templates/initializer.erb) the official template), put there all the config. Let's pretend that we have the model `Product` which you want to list it "under" the model `Shop` and be displayed with the text "New Product". The config should be something like this:

```
config.model 'Product' do
  parent Shop

  label "New Product" 
  label_plural "New Products"
end
```

Comment: `config.model 'Product' do
    list do
      field :id
      field :design_code
      field :brand
      field :never_out_of_stock
      field :is_hidden
      field :filename
      field :created_at
    end
  end`

Something like this is what I have in my `rails_admin.rb`